# Validate array of objects in Node

Tags: node.js, express, knex.js, express-validator, objection.js

I have an array that looks something like this

```
  settings: [
    { key: 'maxImageSize', value: '512' },
    { key: 'maxFileSize', value: '2048' },
    { key: 'searchResultsLimit', value: '10' },
  ]
```

I would like to validate the value of each key before saving them to a database.

**Example**: `searchResultsLimit` should be greater than 1 but never exceed 20.

I am using `Objection.js` and `express-validator`.

Thanks.

Comment: What would you like to do if one of those settings failed validation? just throw an error or  discard it from settings array?

Comment: do you save them as JSON in DB ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that returns a boolean based on whether the array is valid or invalid.

```js
function myValidate(settings) {
  try {
    settings.map((setting) => {
      if (validator.toInt(setting.value) <= 1 || validator.toInt(setting.value) >= 20) {
        console.log(setting.value);
        throw new Error("Invalid");
      }
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Turns out validator.js does not provide a validator to check if a number is in range. Check https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js/issues/330 for details.

In case you want to just ignore the items that are invalid, you can use the filter method instead to get the items in the required range.